# Conditionally write to a compressed stream

Tags: c#, .net

My `Import` method takes some `data` and writes it to a stream.  If the `CompressedStore` property is true, the contents of that stream should be compressed.

This code works, however I just don't like it.  For one, I call `serializer.Serialize()` twice.  I feel this code can be made more concise.  Any ideas?

```
public void Import(IProvisionSource source)
{
   InitializeStore();

   // Call source.Export and populate local data store
   var data = source.Export();
   var serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());

   var file = CompressedStore ? "KPCData.gz" : "KPCData.xml";
   var path = Path.Combine(DataDirectory, file);
   using (var fileWriter = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
   {
      if (CompressedStore)
      {
         using (var writer = new GZipStream(fileWriter, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
         {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         serializer.Serialize(fileWriter, data);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, [`GZipStream` owns the underlying stream, so it disposes it when it's disposed itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ck2z1y). If you're okay with relying on that, then you could put the right `Stream` into a variable and then have just one `using` around it. Something like:

```
var writer = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

if (CompressedStore)
    writer = new GZipStream(writer, CompressionLevel.Optimal);

using (writer)
{
   serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
}
```

This avoids the duplication and so it's shorter, but it's also less obviously correct (`using` combined with `new` is a good pattern, and it's not used here), so I think your original code is actually the better option. If there was more repetition than just one method call, it could make sense to extract that into a separate method, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Ah!  Yea, that was the issue I couldn't get around; I could rewrite it with various conditionals, but every time something wasn't getting disposed.  If disposing of `GZipStream` will also dispose of its `FileStream`, then I'm probably good.  I'll keep this solution in mind!